# Python requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, import, servicenow

I am writing a python script that does these steps below.

- Query a MongoDB database
- Parse and aggregate results
- Upload data to a ServiceNow table via a REST API

This works most of the time but occasionally I see this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

This error stops the script and prevents the entire data set from being captured.

What can I do to alleviate this issue?

Python 2.7.5

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from config import *

import os, sys

mypath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(mypath, "api-python-client"))

from apiclient.mongo import *

from pymongo import MongoClient

import json

import requests

from bson.json_util import dumps

client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)

#Create ServiceNow URL
svcnow_url = create_svcnow_url('u_imp_cmps')

#BITSDB Nmap Collection
db = client[mongo_db]

#Aggregate - RDBMS equivalent to Alias select x as y
#Rename fields to match ServiceNow field names
computers = db['computer'].aggregate([
        {"$unwind": "$hostnames"},
        {"$project" : {
                "_id":0,
                "u_hostname": "$hostnames.name",
                "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4",
                "u_status": "$status.state",
                "u_updated_timestamp": "$last_seen"
        }}

])

j = dumps({"records":computers})
#print(j)


#Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

#Build HTTP Request
response = requests.post(url=svcnow_url, auth=(svcnow_user, svcnow_pwd), headers=headers ,data=j)

#Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Response Text', response.text, 'Error Response:',response.json())
        exit()

#Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
print('Status:',response.status_code,'Headers:',response.headers,'Response:',response.json())
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/computer_pingable_import.py", line 50, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url=svcnow_url, auth=(svcnow_user, svcnow_pwd), headers=headers ,data=j)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 107, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 608, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 737, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 663, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Another attempt and a slightly different error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/computer_pingable_import.py", line 50, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url=svcnow_url, auth=(svcnow_user, svcnow_pwd), headers=headers ,data=j)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 107, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 426, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceNow prevents REST transactions](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Transaction_Quotas#Default_Quota_Rules&gsc.tab=0/) from running for longer than 60 seconds.

I'm not too sure how large your dataset is, but you will want to chunk the data into smaller pieces to ensure the transaction always runs.

Comment: Ah... any suggestions on how to do that? I'm fairly new to python. Thank you.